# grub does not use settings from /etc/default/grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I setup a new ubuntu quantal system and edited `/etc/default/grub` as follows:

```
# If you change this file, run update-grub afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you dont want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=false

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY=false

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Afterwards I ran `update-grub` which reported no errors. However `/boot/grub/menu.lst` still has "quiet splash" in the kernel command line:

```
title   Ubuntu, kernel 3.5.0-17-generic
uuid    3f26e165-5167-43e5-8fa2-aa55f7919d2a
kernel    /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=3f26e165-5167-43e5-8fa2-aa55f7919d2a ro quiet splash 
initrd    /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
quiet

title   Ubuntu, kernel 3.5.0-17-generic (recovery mode)
uuid    3f26e165-5167-43e5-8fa2-aa55f7919d2a
kernel    /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=3f26e165-5167-43e5-8fa2-aa55f7919d2a ro  single
initrd    /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
```

How can fix it, so get rid of the "quiet" and "splash" options?

Comment: I guess you need to remove `quiet splash` manually from the menu.lst/grub2.cfg file. I encountered same issue in Fedora, I guess the update will append other parameters from the previous kernel parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know, 12.10 (and almost most other Ubuntu versions) uses Grub2 and not Grub. One of the [major differences between Grub and Grub2 packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) is that there is no `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file and it has been replaced by `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Your changes to the `/etc/default/grub` will not update the `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file and the command `update-grub` actually only updates the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file.

So, if you would check the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file, you can notice that the kernel command line would no longer have the "quiet splash" in it.

Comment: Grub2 has been used in Ubuntu for quite some time, starting with 9.10, I believe. That's three years now. Editing `/etc/default/grub` and running `update-grub` afterwards is the preferred and supported way of managing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, so OP is doing nothing wrong. Also, what's this about "admitting" to use 12.10? Quantal is the current, newly released stable version of Ubuntu. Nothing wrong with using it (although I prefer LTS releases).

Comment: Until 12.04, grub2 was at version 1.99. From 12.10 onwards, grub2's package version is 2.00.

Comment: No, it is "Grub2", starting with version 1.98. Legacy Grub ("Grub1") was up to version 0.97 and hasn't been used in Ubuntu for three years now. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: If you may read the question, OP is confused that `menu.lst` file is not updated and grub2 never used that file. Anyway, I updated my answer to be less confusing.

Comment: I just looked at my dpkg and it seems there's grub (0.97-29ubuntu66) installed together with grub-common (2.00-7ubuntu11). I'll remove grub and install grub-pc instead and see if it works the next reboot (I cannot reboot now, it's a server...)